# Displaying text without a button

Tags: java, android

I am trying to display some text that the user inputs on a android app. However, all the examples that I can find online require you to hit a button before some text is displayed. Is it possible to display user input without a button?

Comment: Do you use EditText or another component to handle user input? EditText shows input when user adding symbols. To handle changes in EditText or input end event you can use [TextWatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html).

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned @ligi you can use TextWatcher like this:

```
    EditText editText;
    TextView tv;

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            tv.setText(s);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a TextWatcher to your EditText

Comment: Why dosn't a simple textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString()); work?

Comment: @Sruli Because you would need to call that method every time the text is changed, which is what a `TextWatcher` does.